# MySQL Multiple Row Compare

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a query that will compare multiple rows in the same table and shows me all results that match.

For example, my data will look like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+-------+
| activity_id | d_id | tech_id | timestamp  | value |
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+-------+
|    39248078 |    1 |     1 | 2014-03-09 |     1 |
|    39248079 |    2 |     1 | 2014-03-06 |     1 |
|    39248082 |    3 |     1 | 2014-04-09 |     0 |
|    39248085 |    1 |     2 | 2014-03-13 |     1 |
|    39248088 |    3 |     2 | 2014-07-17 |     1 |
|    39248091 |    1 |     3 | 2014-02-07 |     1 |
|    39248093 |    2 |     3 | 2014-12-02 |     0 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+-------+
```

The goal is to get all d_ids where tech_id = 3 AND (tech_id = 1 OR tech_id = 2). So in this case, the result should be 1 and 2 but not 3.

I've looked into subqueries but wasn't able to get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: unclear... can you show the result set?

Comment: you cannot have a tech_id that is equal to 3 and 1 or 2 at the same time.. ???

Comment: The result set I am looking for is: |d_id| 1 | 2

Comment: I basically want to get a list of all d_id's where tech_id is 3, and then filter them against all d_ids where tech_id is either 1 or 2, and get only the ones where d_id is present in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    d_id 
FROM table
WHERE d_id IN(
    SELECT 
        d_id 
    FROM table 
    WHERE tech_id=3
) AND tech_id=1 OR tech_id=2
```

Let me know if it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
with CTE as 
(
 select * from table
 where tech_id = 3
)
select c.d_id 
from CTE c
where tech_id = 2 or tech_id = 3
```

Comment: It wasn't a typo. I basically want to get a list of all d_id's where tech_id is 3, and then filter them against all d_ids where tech_id is either 1 or 2, and get only the ones where d_id is present in both.

Comment: so the end result should be | d_id | 1 | 2

Comment: I could pull the first list of d_ids, then a second list of d_ids and compare them in the application layer, but there must be a way to do this directly in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?
I havent tested it but from what I understand something like this should work

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT activity_id, d_id, tech_id, timestamp, value FROM test
WHERE tech_id = 3
) as temp
JOIN test t on t.d_id = temp.d_id
WHERE t.tech_id = 1 OR t.tech_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

with CTE as 
(
 select * from table
 where tech_id = 3
)
select c.d_id 
from CTE c
where tech_id = 2 or tech_id = 3